# Database structure recommendation for EF Weight-Zone-Price

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework

Please recommand a database structure which will help to eliminate lots of repeating elements.
I have Zone, Weight and Price entities. I would like to have a rate list in my database. Zone and Weight pairs refer to one price.
For example Zone A, 0.5kg will have price of 100. Zone A 1kg will have price 122.
The thing is that my Weight entity varies from 0.5 to 68 with 0.5 step (136 items) and I have around 10 zones each of them will have a price of specific weight as well.
Currently I use the design, which in my opinion is anticipated.

```
Zone | Weight | Price

A| 0.5 |100

A| 1 |123

A| 1.5 |128

(till weight is 68 and afterwards for each zone)

B| 0.5 |140
```

As one option I think of is to group Weight and Zone pairs in one table and use Price and ID combination in another, but that will not have a great impact, will it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create 2 tables zoneweight and price and use the weight table to map zones an prices. That would reduce the amount of data a bit.

```
create table zoneweight (zoneID int primary key, zone varchar([maxlengthofzonename]), weight decimal(2,2));
create table price(price decimal(10,2), fk_zoneID int,
constraint fk_price foreign key (fk_zoneID) references zoneweight(zoneID));
```